# VB.NET restore Backup file created on one server to another server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, backup, restore

i am using SQL server express 2005 as an backend. I created a backup file programmatically.If i use same server , then it restore the data successfuly. however if we try to restore on different server, then it fails. and throw following message

**"The Backup set Holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'DatabaseName' database. RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally**."

On both server, Sql server instance name and database name is same.
Please suggest how can i resolve this error

Answer (score 1):

You need to RESTORE from files (which are contained in the backup set) rather than the backup set directly.  The bottom example is to copy a database, but the idea is the same.:

```
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks 
   TO AdventureWorksBackups ;

RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
   FROM AdventureWorksBackups ;

RESTORE DATABASE TestDB 
   FROM AdventureWorksBackups 
   WITH MOVE 'AdventureWorks_Data' TO 'C:\MySQLServer\testdb.mdf',
   MOVE 'AdventureWorks_Log' TO 'C:\MySQLServer\testdb.ldf';
GO
```